# How to remove unncessary whitespaces between two lonely figures on page

Tags: tables, positioning, align, blank-page

Im sure it's an easy question but I cant figure it out and I was searching google for different keywords crossing my mind but couldn't find a relevant post.

I have two tables which are positioned on a new page (last page of the chapter) because they don't fit on the page before:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lcl}
            \toprule
                \textbf{asd} & \phantom{-} & \textbf{asd} \\  
                \cmidrule{1-1} \cmidrule{3-3} 
                asd &&  asd\\
                asd &&  asd\\
            \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{blaa}\label{tab:asd}
\end{table}%
%
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lcl}
            \toprule
                \textbf{asd} & \phantom{-} & \textbf{asd} \\  
                \cmidrule{1-1} \cmidrule{3-3} 
                asd &&  asd\\
                asd &&  asd\\
            \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{blaa22}\label{asd22}
\end{table}%
```

The output results in:

[image]

I'd like to remove all those blank lines and just put both tables right to the top of the page. Modifying the alignments of the tables to `[t]` or `[h]` doesn't help either.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: If you put those two `tabular`'s into separate `table` environments, you should be ready to see them float apart from each other. If you want to keep them close to each other, put them in the same `table`, possibly as subfloats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put *both* tabulars into *one* `table` environment:

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcl} \toprule
        \textbf{asd} & \phantom{-} & \textbf{asd} \\\cmidrule{1-1} \cmidrule{3-3} 
        asd &&  asd\\
        asd &&  asd\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{blaa}\label{tab:asd}

\begin{tabular}{lcl}\toprule
    \textbf{asd} & \phantom{-} & \textbf{asd} \\  \cmidrule{1-1} \cmidrule{3-3} 
    asd &&  asd\\
    asd &&  asd\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{blaa22}\label{asd22}
\end{table}
```

Comment: That removed the space between the two tables... but the table still is NOT placed at the top of the page but right in the vertical center.

Comment: Okay fixed it myself using the positioning `\begin{table}[H]`